# Storybook does not refresh after save

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have created a Storybook and after when I change something and save it, the browser does not refresh automatically. So every time I have to press the F5 button. Unfortunately, I could not figure the problem.

I start the storybook with:

```
yarn storybook
```

The repository is hosted on https://github.com/softshipper/react-storybook.

**Update**

I have figured out that on Firefox hot reload works like a charm. However, on Chromium hot reload does not work at all. I am using https://pop.system76.com/ as OS and Chromium is installed with flatpak.

When I start the storybook, in the terminal it shows me:

```
$ start-storybook -p 6006
info @storybook/react v6.2.7
info 
info => Loading presets
info => Loading 1 config file in "/home/developer/projects/openidea/webapp/components/.storybook"
info => Loading 7 other files in "/home/developer/projects/openidea/webapp/components/.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in "/home/developer/projects/openidea/webapp/components/.storybook/main.js"
WARN unable to find package.json for @rollup/plugin-node-resolve
WARN unable to find package.json for rollup
info => Using prebuilt manager
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
WARN unable to find package.json for @rollup/plugin-node-resolve
WARN unable to find package.json for rollup
info => Using React fast refresh
info => Using default Webpack4 setup
(node:145138) DeprecationWarning: Default PostCSS plugins are deprecated. When switching to '@storybook/addon-postcss',
you will need to add your own plugins, such as 'postcss-flexbugs-fixes' and 'autoprefixer'.

See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-default-postcss-plugins for details.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
10% building 6/12 modules 6 active /home/developer/projects/openidea/webapp/components/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--4-0!/home/developer/projects/openidea/webapp/components/.storybook/generated-stories-entry.jsinfo => Using cached manager
webpack built preview 6002361e38573b1c5351 in 9449ms
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                     │
│   Storybook 6.2.7 started                           │
│   9.74 s for preview                                │
│                                                     │
│    Local:            http://localhost:6006/         │
│    On your network:  http://192.168.178.27:6006/    │
│                                                     │
╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
webpack building...
webpack built preview 533a9b622317ca763dd0 in 1930ms
```

Comment: In my case, it is `-s src`

Comment: I have tried the following `"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src",` and it does not work.

Comment: What it does not work on Chromium, but on Firefox works like a charm.

Comment: When you start storybook in chromium do you see any abnormal messages in the terminal when building/starting up or browser console once it's running?

Comment: I have updated my post.